# FTP service for use on Windows Server?

Tags: iis, windows, ftp

We always use IIS' FTP service but recently we have had a few problems with it; what FTP service do you recomend for IIS?

We use Windows Server and Windows XP in the clients.

A free version is a must, We are now considering FileZilla and WarFtp, We will be having 100 concurrent connections.

Comment: do you prefer a single port SFTP (port 22)  or a dual port FTP(21+20)/FTPS(990+989) solution?

Comment: single port is fine, but dual port is better

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Filezilla; it's free, easy to set up and manage but very powerful. Ability to use non directory users is a big plus.

Comment: +1: It's free and extremely stable.

Comment: I would second this.  And it is free

Comment: It's also quite easy to integrate Filezilla's users with LDAP or active directory, because the config is a very easy-to-parse XML file.

Answer (score 5):

My company makes a high quality file server with access points for FTP/FTPS/SFTP/WebDav/HTTP/HTTPS.

The product name is [Null FTP Server](http://www.vwsolutions.com/NullFTPServer/) and there is a free version available.

**Some of the features:**

- REST HTTP API to control the server
- Remote administration for 1 or more servers.
- x86 and x64 variants are available.
- User authentication is supported with windows user accounts, active directory, and/or built-in accounts.
- You can either lock a user account into a directory or use the server's root directory.
- Virtual directories are also supported.
- [several other key features](http://www.vwsolutions.com/NullFTPServer/features.aspx) and [screenshots](http://www.vwsolutions.com/NullFTPServer/screenshots.aspx)

Comment: I have to say, that I was skeptical at first and I tried your FTP server and its great.  Great job with that.  The config screen for SSL access is especially nice... great job making it easy to understand.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

IIS7 has a [completely new FTP component](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1619) (separate download!) which is a big step up - try to upgrade to Server 2008 and use it if possible ;)

A few of the "features" are ftp over ssl, better user isolation, utf8 and ipv6, support for virtual hosts (think web host header separation)...

Comment: +1 for 2008 FTP service, used it & its great

Answer (score 2):

We just deployed [Gene6 FTP Server](http://www.g6ftpserver.com/) onto our shared platform. It performs pretty well (1200-1300 sites per server), it's not expensive, and it has a COM API so you can script pretty much all of the configuration without too much fuss.

**Edit:**

When OP originally asked this question *'A free version is a must'* was not specified at the time I answered.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't give you the downvote but im surprised you got a vote at all with a ftp server suggestion that costs money...

Comment: When OP originally asked the question he/she didn't specify that it should be free.

Answer (score 1):

The two biggies are [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org) (free) and [Serv-U](http://www.serv-u.com). I've had really good luck with both of them. Serv-U has gotten progressively more expensive over the years. I seem to remember it being really cheap at some point.

Comment: I used Serv-U for years and was curious on the price.  I do believe it has gone up some but I don't remember what I've paid for it in the past.

Answer (score 1):

WarFTP? Please: http://www.warftp.org/

Answer (score 0):

A collage of mine recommend WarFTP? Any info about this?

Comment: Haven't used it in a LONG while, but if I recall there were security issues.