# FTP, SCP or something else

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp, sftp, scp

I've just got my own virtual server running Windows Server 2008 and I'm setting it up. However, I'm far from an expert and I'm not sure about a few things.

I want to be able to move files to and from my server and I was wondering what the best way of doing this was.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Answers all good, also looking at http://serverfault.com/questions/612/ftp-service-for-use-on-windows-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**freeSSHd**](http://www.freesshd.com/?ctt=overview) has **Secure FTP** and **SCP** and **SSH** support.

I answered this earlier at -- [Possible to have SFTP Server in Vista Home Basic Edition?](https://serverfault.com/questions/36215/possible-to-have-sftp-server-in-vista-home-basic-edition)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you are trying to do.  If you aren't worried about encrypting the files in transit then you can just set up an IIS FTP site that authenticates with the local machine privileges.  If you want something that encrypts traffic then you should look for SCP or SFTP as suggested by nik.

Answer (score 2):

We generally use [CopSSH](http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh). Very easy to install, and in addition to SFTP we use it to log into the server with Putty if Remote Desktop isn't responding. I recommend changing the sshd conf file to have it listen on an alternate high port (like 7412 or something) to avoid port scanners.

Answer (score 1):

Filezilla has both a FTP client and FTP server, which I would recommend if you want to go the FTP route. Which is of course, open source and free.

http://filezilla-project.org/